# Is there a Shazam-Like API?

Tags: ios, siri, sirishortcuts, shazam

I write programs using Apple's Siri Shortcuts, and I am looking for an API or any way that can be used to identify a song playing in the background.

Is there any software that can do this?  If not, is there a way to write a Shortcut that IDs a song?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't provide any helpful information, the only approved response doesn't work and it's a copyright violation.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Gracenote:

"
Gracenote (which is owned by Sony) has opened up it's SDKs and APIs and has a proper dev portal. 
You can check out the app "Track ID" on Play Store which I am sure will give you better results than Shazam or Soundhound. Track ID uses the Gracenote services. Having access to the huge Sony Music collection, Gracenote does a much better job of ACR than Shazam (especially, me being Indian, I find Gracenote recognising a lot of Hindi, Bengali, Tamil songs, which Shazam or Soundhound only are able to recognise English ones)."

Gracenote.com

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: It’s from Quora i Will provide a link

Comment: Don’t forget to upvote and accept

Comment: I tried it but it says that it's not working now so I can't add an app.

Comment: I’m sorry to hear, I think that’s only one similar as far as I know.

Comment: You still haven't put the link

Comment: Pretty sure this is the link: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-API-for-Shazam-or-SoundHound/answer/Arnav-Gupta-3

edit: It's pretty old (>3 yrs), so it's a bit misleading to re-post here as an answer in 2019.

Comment: @bodecker well not really. It’s still being maintained.